# Trying to use a class but nothing is printed. No errors are generated. Am I missing something?

Tags: c++, c++11

No errors are generated, but nothing is printed when I run the code. Help?

```
class NatalieClass{
  public: 
    void setName(string x){
      x = name;
    }

    string getName(){
      return name;
    }

  private:
    string name;
};

int main(){
  NatalieClass ob1;
  ob1.setName("Hello World");
  cout << ob1.getName();
  return 0;
}
```

The function is supposed to print "Hello World" but instead nothing is printed.

Comment: Instead of `x = name;`, try `name = x;` in `setName` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `setName`:

```
void setName(string x){
  x = name;
}
```

You are setting the argument you get passed (which is `"Hello World"` in this example) to the member variable `x`, which is an empty string. Then you print out `name`, which is still an empty string, so it'll look like you print out nothing.

You probably meant to assign `name` to `x` instead of the other way around:

```
void setName(string x) {
  name = x;
}
```

---

<sub>Side note : seeing your code snippet I'm assuming you have `using namespace std;` somewhere at the top, this is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), use `std::` instead..</sub>